# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \gcd(i,j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i) [n/i]^2$

Tags: number-theory

I found very interesting formula, $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \gcd(i,j) = \sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i)[ n/i ]^2$ at [A018806](https://oeis.org/A018806). Here $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
How to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of pairs whose gcd is divisible by $k$ is $\phi(k)[n/k]^2$.
From $n=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$, $\gcd(i,j)$ is counted $\gcd(i,j)$ times.
 This is nothing but the proof itself. For example, gcd=6 is counted 
$φ(1)+φ(2)+φ(3)+φ(6)=6$ times.